# How can I connect to a remote machine via TCP and UDP with Perl?

Tags: perl, networking, ipc

I have a script that runs on a server and I want it now to send messages to my PC. I want to send TCP or UDP messages to some port.

What is the best way to do this (a tutorial will be great)?

And is there some client program that I can run on my PC that will listen to a local port for the messages?

Answer (score 8):

A client can send TCP and UDP messages using a socket, for example:

```
use IO::Socket;
my $socket = IO::Socket::INET->new(PeerAddr => 'theserver',
    PeerPort => '1234', Proto => 'tcp', Type => SOCK_STREAM);
print $socket "Hello server!";
close($socket);
```

A server has to listen on a port, and accept messages that arrive on it:

```
my $socket = new IO::Socket::INET (LocalHost => 'hostname',
    LocalPort => '1234', Proto => 'tcp', Listen => 1, Reuse => 1);
my $incoming = $sock->accept();
while(<$incoming>) {
    print $_;
}
close($incoming);
```

This is just the tip of the iceberg, but hopefully this will help to get you started.

Comment: Do you know some port sniffer that can listen to my port ?
nNot heavy things like wireshark ...

Comment: Port sniffers display network traffic, but they don't actually listen.  There's a utility called netcat that can listen, for example `nc -l -p 1234` http://www.catonmat.net/blog/unix-utilities-netcat/

Answer (score 2):

Start with reading of [perlipc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html) documentation - it contains examples of simple servers and clients, with a lot of very important addons (like: how to properly daemonize).

Answer (score 1):

Although a bit dated, you want want to find a copy of [Network Programming with Perl](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201615711) by Lincoln Stein.  Also, look at the Perl modules with [Socket](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=socket&mode=module) in their names.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do it. One of the easiest is to have your program email your email address. In Perl, you can use, e.g. [Email::Send](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Email::Send). Other ways include sockets, or having your program access a web server on your PC. It depends what facilities you want to use. I usually use a `ssh` command to access other computers across a network.

Comment: I am newbie for perl , and we dont have smtp  server on that server .

Comment: It isn't very clear what you want to do, so I can't give a clear answer.

Comment: I want to send tcp or udp massages to some port .

Answer (score 0):

You could use Net Send if your on windows, Write "Net Help Send" for more info in CMD i don't know perl but start CMD Net Send Computer Message

Make sure thet the net send service is running... google it for more info.

Comment: And on sp3 the default is blocked